# Optimize Mysql query with boolean value

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `blocked` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  KEY `supplier_id` (`supplier_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

'approved' is a boolean 0/1 field
'blocked' and 'allowed' hold country codes such as "US CA FR"

I run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT supplier_id 
FROM products 
WHERE (
    supplier_id=0 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207077 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207087 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207079 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207082 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207083 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207086 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207084 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207078 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207085 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207094 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207097 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207095 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207089 OR 
    supplier_id = 1207091
) AND (
    (`blocked` NOT LIKE '%US%' AND `allowed` ='') OR 
    `allowed` LIKE '%US%'
) AND approved=1;
```

It runs in about 0.02s. Any suggestions on how to optimize it? Thank you.

Comment: add index on supplier_id, approved, blocked and allowed. Make approved come in first in the AND clause

Comment: You can also get rid of all those ORs and use supplier_id IN (0, 1207077, 1207087, ...)

Comment: @Brian its gonna be the same thing in background anyways...won't improve the performance.

Comment: @Steve - I added indexes as you suggested and moved the 'approved' to first position in WHERE clause, but unfortunately the execution speed is the same as before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The execution speed is the same because OR and non left anchored LIKE clauses cannot use indexes appropriately. You've got bad table design in that US FR etc field, that should be in another table that you join against. If you are stuck with your design and the table is vey large, then create a derived table for the supplier_id OR clauses and then JOIN against the same table in order to find the rest of the matches. This may also require a UNION since you have other OR's. For more information:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-btree-hash.html
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to optimize it as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT supplier_id FROM products WHERE ((`blocked` NOT LIKE '%US%' AND 
`allowed` ='') OR `allowed` LIKE '%US%') AND approved=1 AND supplier_id IN (1207077, 
1207087, 1207079, 1207082, 1207083, 1207086, 1207084, 1207078, 1207085, 1207094, 
1207097, 1207095, 1207089, 1207091);
```

It runs at 0.0004s now.

Thank you winmutt for pointing me to the right direction :-)

Comment: I see no essential difference between this query and the original.